# What don't structs created with a initilzer function get exported to test packages?

Tags: go

Say we have a struct and a constructor function for the structure like such

```
package myPackage

type Client struct {
    a TypeA
    b TypeB
}

func NewClient(a TypeA, b TypeB) ConcreteClient {
    return &Client{
        a: a,
        b: b,
    }
}

type ConcreteClient interface {
    ExportedFunc()
}

func (c *Client) privateFunc() {
    // ...
}

func (c *Client) ExportedFunc() {
    // ...
}
```

And we use this client in a test package like such

```
var (
    c = &Client {
        a:a,
        b:b,
    }
)

func TestUnexported(t *testing.T) {
    c.privateFunc() // Works
}
```

In the previous case the unexported is discovered as expected in the test file but when we use the constructor like this

```
var (
    c = NewClient()
)

func TestUnexported(t *testing.T) {
    c.privateFunc() // Doesn't work
}
```

The unexported method isn't exposed for testing. These files exist within the same package and follow the *_test naming pattern.I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is going on scoping wise as to why the unexported methods are hidden when created through a constructor and not through typical construction.

- Edited for clarity

Comment: You should be able to call the unexported methods if you're in the same package. Is `c` typed as an interface?

Comment: Your constructor's return type is defined as `ConcreteClient`, therefore `c`'s type is not `Client` but `ConcreteClient` which is, i assume, an interface which in Go does not provide access to fields, exported or unexported, only to methods defined by that interface.

Comment: "why the unexported methods are hidden when created through a constructor" makes no sense at all.

Comment: What is the definition of `ConcreteClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a type as an interface or accept an interface in a function, then the type is reduced to *only* the methods in that interface and everything else will be inaccessible. You've effective "converted" the type from `Client` to `ConcreteClient`.

Consider how the code would look if *all* methods from *all* types be readily accessible:

```
func f(fp io.Reader) {
    fp.Seek(42)
}
```

How annoying would such a function be to use: "you can pass any `io.Reader` to this, but oh, it must also have the `Seek()` method or you'll get compile errors".

This is why additional interfaces such as `io.ReadSeeker` (which has `Read()` and `Seek()`) exist.

---

Not all is lost, you can still use access everything from the type methods:

```
func (c *Client) ExportedFunc() string {
    return c.a
}

func main() {
    cclient := NewClient("this is a", "this is b")
    fmt.Printf(cclient.ExportedFunc())
}
```

Or you can use a type assertion to get the original type back:

```
cclient := NewClient("this is a", "this is b")
client, ok := cclient.(*Client)
if !ok {
    fmt.Printf("not a Client: %T\n", cclient)
    os.Exit(1)
}
fmt.Printf("a: %v\n", client.a)
```